# pass a variable value from code behind to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a hidden variable in my .aspx page.

```
  input type="hidden" runat="server" id="isdup"
```

Now in code behind i check for certain conditions and assign isdup a value accordingly. However, this may not help you much but this is what i do in code behind.

```
            bool exist = (from n in mCDC.NCDCPoints
                          where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == eventID
                          where n.BeginDate == begin
                          where n.EndDate == end
                          select n).Count() > 0;

    try
    {
        if (!exist)
        {
            //do this before insert so the insert will have correct values
            isdup.Value = "false";
            SaveAllColumnFields(ref ncdc, e);
            mCDC.NCDCPoints.InsertOnSubmit(ncdc);
            mCDC.SubmitChanges();
            //do this after insert because it wont work until the ncdc object
            //has been assigned an ID
            SaveAllDynamicFields(mCDC, ref ncdc, e);
            mCDC.SubmitChanges();
            Grid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            isdup.Value = "true";
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(isdup.Value);
        }
```

Now I need to access the isdup inside javascript. However the problem has been that those values are not passed and isdup is null.

```
    var showus= document.getElementById("<%=isdup.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(showus);
    if(showus == "true")
    {
      Showduplicate();
    }
```

So, kindly let me know the mistake i have been doing?

Comment: What version of .net?  4.0 resolved these types of issues

Comment: Why are you using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox is an ASP.net application?

Comment: how do you pass isdup to the view?

Comment: @Cybernate: I just used it to check the values.

Comment: @Chris Lively: I'm using .net 3.5

Comment: When you view source, does the var showus= document... line have the actual id of the hidden control?

Comment: @Chris: No , it has ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_isdup as the id

Answer (score 2):

Hve you tried with:

```
  var showus= document.getElementById('<%=isdup.ClientID %>').value;
```

**update**

is javascript at the end of the page?

**update**

try to put this code in the page:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="isdup" runat="server"  Value="eee"/>
    <script>
        var showus = document.getElementById("<%=isdup.ClientID %>").value;
        alert(showus);
</script>
```

this works for me!

**update**

in page_load...

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientscript"))
{
   string script1 = "<script language=JavaScript>";
   script1 += "var showus= document.getElementById('" + isdup.ClientID + "').value;";
   script1 += "alert(showus);";
   script1 += "</script>";

   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "clientscript", script1);
}
```

my example:

```
 protected void pagesTree_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
   {
        PageStructure page = pageService.GetPage(Guid.Parse(e.Node.Value));

        this.LoadPageData(page);

        isdup.Value = "xxx";
    }
```

**update**

```
         bool exist = (from n in mCDC.NCDCPoints
                      where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == eventID
                      where n.BeginDate == begin
                      where n.EndDate == end
                      select n).Count() > 0;

 if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientscript"))
{
   string script1 = "<script language=JavaScript>";
   script1 += "var showus= document.getElementById('" + isdup.ClientID + "').value;";
   script1 += "alert(showus);";
   script1 += "</script>";

   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "clientscript", script1);
}


try
{
    if (!exist)
    {
        //do this before insert so the insert will have correct values
        isdup.Value = "false";
        SaveAllColumnFields(ref ncdc, e);
        mCDC.NCDCPoints.InsertOnSubmit(ncdc);
        mCDC.SubmitChanges();
        //do this after insert because it wont work until the ncdc object
        //has been assigned an ID
        SaveAllDynamicFields(mCDC, ref ncdc, e);
        mCDC.SubmitChanges();
        Grid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        isdup.Value = "true";
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(isdup.Value);
    }
```

Comment: No, it is not the end of page

Comment: Try move your javascript after the hidden field... like at the end of the page!

Comment: I just tried this thing.. It didn't.... It shows 'eee' but not the value from code behind.

Comment: The thing has been that i have been updating isdup value outside the main.... So, do you think thats a mistake?

Comment: I've update the post and now it read the value from server code!

Comment: Hey it actually read xxx from page_load. But i need it from a method that is outside page_load.. So, the value is not read from there.

Comment: I've updated the post... script must be registered on page_load and it read hidden field value. I tried and it shows the popup properly even if I set "isdup" in a different method! Try to set the hidden field in a simplest way you can just for a test!

Comment: I just checked it. But it is taking only the values set inside page_load but it is not getting the value of isdup from other method

Comment: this is the hidden field maybe something different here:   <asp:HiddenField ID="isdup" runat="server"  />

Comment: ok try putting registerStartupScript command inside the method where you set the hidden field...

Comment: I tried to use registerclientblockscript as it is not startup script. But it does not go into the loop.

Comment: I've updated including script in your method... have you tried this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery code.

```
var showus= $("#<%=isdup.ClientID %>").val();
```

Replace your `input` field and try this with jquery code

UPDATED

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="isdup" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var showus = $("#<%=isdup.ClientID %>").val();
    alert(showus);
    if (showus == "true") {
        Showduplicate();
     }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The thing has been that i have been updating isdup value outside the main.... So, do you think that's a mistake?

Comment: @Nishanth: I have updated my answer, just copy-past that code and try it.

Comment: @Nishanth: this is because you are not able to get jquery file reference.

Comment: @Nishanth: goto http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js and save file as `jquery-1.4.1.min.js` and then add this file into your solution explorer.